# Mock PackageManager using Robolectric and Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I have a method in my sut class that calls PackageManager :

`var intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE_NAME)`

I want to mock this to be able to unit test it. 
is there a way to do that using Robolectric or/and Mockito ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's the sample with AndroidX, Robolectric and Mockito

```
val context = spy(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

val packageManager = mock(PackageManager::class.java)
doReturn(packageManager).`when`(context).packageManager
doReturn(mock(Intent::class.java)).`when`(packageManager).getLaunchIntentForPackage(anyString())
```